# How to declare a local pointer that is compatible with pointer of multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers

For example, I have a global pointer to multi-dimensional array like this:

```
char ** arr[12][12][12];
```

In a function, I want to declare a local variable to assign with the above pointer:

```
int func() {
    char **p[12][12][12] = arr;
    return 0;
}
```

But g++ won't allow. How do I properly create compatiable pointer?

Comment: `char ** arr[12][12][12];` is not a pointer. It is an three-dimensional array of pointers to pointer to `char`. Yes, it can decay... but to pointer to two-dimensional array... You however, are trying to assign arrays.

Comment: Did you mean `char*(* arr)[12][12][12]`? That would be a pointer to a m.d. array.

Comment: If you have `foo bar[42][53];`, you turn this into a type with `typedef foo foo_array[42][53];` and then you can declare a pointer to it with `foo_array* pbar;`. I prefer this over @zenith's (correct!) suggestion because I find it more readable. Also, the same technique works with functions and references, too.

Comment: @LogicStuff had it correctly. I was confused, but yes, how do I assign a three-dimensional array of pointers to pointer to a local variable?

Comment: Arrays are not copyable. However, when wrapping them into a struct, the compiler will generate a copy constructor that does the right thing. In general, avoid copying though.

Comment: @Amumu Do you want to make a copy of `arr`? That requires loops. `std::array` will copy elements for you.

Comment: `char ** arr[12][12][12];` has "refactor me, please!" written all over it.

Comment: If `std::array` is copyable, forget what I suggested four comments up!

Comment: Well, that was a random multiple-choice interview question, and I am curious how to do it. The answers only have assignments to local pointers, and not using anything from standard library. Doing it like this in C with (using `gcc`):  `char *(*p)[12][12][12] = arr;` only generates a warning, but it's an error with `g++`.

Comment: Well, it's wrong in C, too. Think about it, the pointer to the array needs one more asterisk than the array itself!

Answer (score 4):

**Easy alternative: references**

If you just want to use refer to the same array using a different name (or passing a parameter), you could consider using references instead of pointers:

```
using pt = decltype(arr);
pt &p = arr;
```

[Online demo here](http://ideone.com/RWRlSj)

**Alternative with additional pointer indirection**

You could also pass a pointer, by adding an additional level of indirection (see Quentin's comment):

```
pt *pp = &arr; 
cout << *(*pp)[1][2][3]<<endl;
```

It's less readable,  as you have to dereference your pointer before using indexing.

**Hard way: pointer to pointers to pointers ...**

But you won't be able to pass a pointer that will directly access your array elements with the syntax that you expect (i.e. without adding a level of indirection). This works only for unidimensional pointers:

```
char s[500]; 
char *p=s; 
p[15];  s[15];   // both refer to the same element;
```

To use the same kind of approach for multidimensional arrays, you have to change the approach drastically : indexing a pointer refers to an element in a unidimensional array and the size of the unidimensional array is not known by the compiler.  So you have to use several successive unidimensional indirection to have multidimensional indexing.

You would hence use a `char*****` pointer.  This is not so handy because first it's no so readable, and second you have to build a multidimensional pointer structure of unidimensional arrays, whereas the `char**` pointers in `arr` are all stored consecutively:

```
char *****mp = new char****[12];
for (int i=0; i<12; i++) 
{
    mp[i] = new char***[12];
    for (int j=0; j<12; j++) 
        mp[i][j] = arr[i][j];   // attention use same array - if you'd want to clone 
                                // you'd have to allocate the last array and copy elemnts
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/g7qgkB)

Don't forget that you'd have to delete[] all these intermediate arrays,  which makes all this not so easy to use.

**A better approach**

A better approach would be to use vectors:

```
vector<vector<vector<char**>>> arr;
```

The huge advantage is that with this approach, you can very easily pass by reference, or pass the vectors by copy (which is not possible for arrays) and use multidimensional indexing (as each vector knwos its own size).

No complex memory management issue anymore. Perfect flexibility.

Comment: "pointers basically refer to unidimensional arrays" -- Um, no they don't ? You can very well form and use a pointer to a multidimensional array, like any other pointer.

Comment: @Quentin: Perhaps one could say that multi-dimensional arrays in C++ are just a special case of unidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe I used a confusing wording.  What I wanted to explain is that pointer arithmetic is unidimensional.  Of course, pointers of pointers allow you to have a multidimensional structures, but the first level of indirections refers to a unidimensional array of pointers, which themselves refer to a unidmensional array of poitners... and so on until you have all your dimensions.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes ! Thanks ! that's what I wanted to say in my comment - I like your much shorter formulation ;-)

Comment: I should have quoted the entire sentence : even if I just misunderstood that fragment, you *can* do whatever you want with a pointer to multidimensional array, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/179c646ac906d91d).

Comment: @Quentin ok, but you add another level of indirection.  I've understood that OP intended to use p as the original array (like `char arr[12]; char *p=arr; p[3];`).  By the way, I've edited the wording to make it less ambiguous following your precedent remark.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you meant now. You should probably remove the mention to "multidimensional array" -- your answer doesn't, in fact, manipulate any -- and add an actual section about them (not very different, in fact, from the references one).

Comment: @Quentin I agree: I've edited following your advice.  I hope this shows better the nuance between the different approaches.